# Google Cloud Function with Github Actions - ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Build failed with status:

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deployment, google-cloud-functions, github-actions, python-3.10

I have the following github actions file in `.github/workflows/deploy.yml`:

```
name: Deploy

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - id: "auth"
        uses: "google-github-actions/auth@v1"
        with:
          credentials_json: "${{ secrets.GOOGLE_CLOUD_KEY }}"

      - name: "Set up Cloud SDK"
        uses: "google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@v1"

      - name: Deploy Cloud Function
        run: |
          gcloud functions deploy name-of-function \
            --gen2 \
            --region=europe-west1 \
            --runtime=python310 \
            --source=src/directory_of_main_py \
            --entry-point=entry_function_in_main_py \ 
            --stage-bucket=test-temp \
            --memory=256MB \
            --timeout=180 \
            --trigger-http
```

Whenever I deploy this the first steps run fine on github cloud. However, when it comes to deploying the Cloud function it fails during the build process with:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Build failed with status: FAILURE and message: An unexpected error occurred. Refer to build logs:
```

The logs show the same generic error message. I have tried for ours to understand the issue and I think it is related to the github shell and particularly the path of `--source`. Again, I tried everything from using relative paths and `{{github.workspace}}`
in front of `/source`.

It always returns the same error.

Does anyone know what I could do?

If I run the `gcloud functions....` command from my local prompt it works just fine...

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Is the stage bucket name correct?

Comment: Yes it is. I changed it before I pasted it here for privacy reasons....

Comment: As I said, It works perfectly fine when I run it from my local shell in my root directory. I strongly assume it has something to do with the environment that github executes the gcloud command in...

Comment: Does anyone else have a clue what might be missing? This is extremely frustrating, I read through all the docs, changed every piece of my yml and tried multiple other ways - they all fail.

Comment: I looked into the issue further: It seems that the github actions deployment does not actually upload the function correctly into the cloud storage bucket but overwrites it with "an empty file". Once the build step is trying to fetch the function it tries 3 times and then times out since the fetched object from cloud storage is empty.

`ERROR: error fetching storage source: generic::unknown: retry budget exhausted (3 attempts): fetching gcs source: unpacking source from gcs: source fetch container exited with non-zero status: 1`

and

`warning [/tmp/source-archive.zip]: zipfile is empty`

Comment: So my problem is that the upload of the function is not working correctly. I googled above errors in my context but unsure what the root issue is here. I assume my `source` path is not correct, hence it is not uploading `main.py`and `requirements.txt` correctly. Could also be an auth issue since it works perfectly from my local prompt and only fails via github actions...

Comment: I had the "zipfile is empty" error and it turned out I was calling the gcloud command from the wrong directory in relation to the -- source param

Comment: This answer should help for gen2 cloud functions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77337408/1759443

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when trying to deploy my function via Azure DevOps with the same generic error message. Turned out that I had not given a full path (relative path from the root of the repo) to the `--source` param.
However, your path seems fine... so hard to tell